# RavenDB query documents NOT referenced in related document

Tags: ravendb

```
public class LedgerItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Order
{
    ...
    public IList<OrderLine> OrderLines { get; private set; }
    ...
}

public class OrderLine
{
    ...
    public List<string> LedgerItemIds { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I need to find all LedgerItems that are NOT referenced by Id in any Order.OrderLines.LedgerItemIds.

So far I have tried creating a Multi-Map/Reduce index to select all LedgerItems from LedgerItems and Orders and then Reduce to group by LedgerItemId and Sum the Count.
Then my plan was to query by Count == 1, since that means it only exist once in the group.

```
public class LedgerItemResult
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string ProTeriaCustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Collection { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class LedgerItemsFromLedgerItemsAndOrdersGroupById : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<LedgerItemResult>
{
    public LedgerItemsFromLedgerItemsAndOrdersGroupById()
    {
        AddMap<LedgerItem>(
            ledgeritems => from ledgeritem in ledgeritems
            where (decimal)ledgeritem.Amount < 0m
            select new
            {
                Id = ledgeritem.Id,
                CreatedDate = ledgeritem.TimeStamp,
                ProTeriaCustomerId = ledgeritem.ProTeriaCustomerId,
                Collection = MetadataFor(ledgeritem)["Raven-Entity-Name"].ToString(),
                Count = 1
            }
        );

        AddMap<Order>(
            orders => from order in orders
            from orderline in order.OrderLines
            from ledgeritemid in orderline.LedgerItemIds
            select new
            {
                Id = ledgeritemid,
                CreatedDate = order.CreatedDateTime,
                ProTeriaCustomerId = order.ProTeriaCustomerId,
                Collection = MetadataFor(order)["Raven-Entity-Name"].ToString(),
                Count = 1
            }
        );

        Reduce = results =>
            from result in results
            group result by result.Id into g
            select new LedgerItemResult
            {
                Id = g.First().Id,
                CreatedDate = g.First().CreatedDate,
                ProTeriaCustomerId = g.First().ProTeriaCustomerId,
                Collection = g.First().Collection,
                Count = g.Sum(x => x.Count)
            };

        Stores.Add(x => x.Id, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Stores.Add(x => x.CreatedDate, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Stores.Add(x => x.ProTeriaCustomerId, FieldStorage.Yes);
        Stores.Add(x => x.Collection, FieldStorage.Yes);

        MaxIndexOutputsPerDocument = 250;
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to be working correctly though. I tried querying on Count == 1 and Count == 2 and got way too many results for Count == 1 and I manually checked one of the LedgerItemIds returned to see if it was actually referenced by an Order, and it was, although it shouldn't.

There are probably much easier ways to accomplish this, but I'm still somewhat used to thinking in terms of SQL.

I hope to find a way to accomplish this so I can query the index with Lucene syntax in Management Studio and also by LiINQ in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was on the right track, but was tricked for a while because the disk was almost full. It probably crossed the "stop indexing when too little disk space"-treshold while indexing was running and the indexes created was inconsistent.